# How to compute the autocorrelation and how can I find the lag time?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

If I have the following matrix which represent the random process $X(t)=5 \sin (2t+\theta)$. The columns are the time series and the rows are random theta between $0$ and $\pi$.
$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
        0 &   \phantom{-}3.5355 &   \phantom{-}0.0000 &   \phantom{-}5.0000  &  \phantom{-}3.5355    &     0 \\
    1.0000  &  \phantom{-}1.7436  & -4.5465   &-2.0807   &-4.6862    &\phantom{-}4.5465 \\
    2.0000&   -4.9867  &  \phantom{-}3.7840&   -3.2682&    \phantom{-}0.3647  & -3.7840 \\
    3.0000 &   \phantom{-}2.4068  &  \phantom{-}1.3971  &  \phantom{-}4.8009   & \phantom{-}4.3826  & -1.3971
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I compute the auto-correlation using the time average?

How can I compute the auto-correlation using the statistical average?

I have a confusion about the lags time? What is it in the both cases and how to determine it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For me anyhow, you need to define 'time average' and 'statistical average' in this context. If you had the sequence $x = (1,3,6,4,2)$ and found the correlation between $x_1 = (1,3,6,4)$ and $x_2 = (3, 6,4,2)$ then that would be autocorrelation of lag 1. A slight variation from ordinary correlation is that most authors use the _whole sequence_ $x$ when finding the sample means and SDs needed for the correlation.

Comment: In the formal to compute the autocorrelation , there is 1/n , what is the value n ? it could be the length or x or x1 or x2 ?

Comment: In addition, if I have a matrix 1000* 100 ? how many lag times should I run ?

Comment: $n$ is the length of the sequence. Don't know the context of your problem and data, so I can't answer. Maybe someone with more experience using autocorrelation in economics can guess what you're to do. Or maybe you could provide more background information.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment continued:** Some software computes an *autocorrelation function* showing a 'reasonable' number' of lags (depending on sample size). I am not familiar with applications of autocorrelation that consider only a *single* lag.

The following R program simulates the first 2000 steps of a Markov Chain that takes values $0$ and $1.$ Then it plots the first 100 values (mostly 0's) and graphs the autocorrelation function (ACF) of all results.

```
set.seed(1234);  m = 2000; x = numeric(m); x[i] = 0
alpha = .1;  beta = .5
for (i in 2:m) {
  if (x[i-1]==0) x[i] = rbinom(1, 1, alpha)
  else           x[i] = rbinom(1, 1, 1-beta)
  }
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x[1:100], type="l")
acf(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

The first bar in the ACF plot shows autocorrelation at 0 lag (so autocorrelation 1), the successive bars show autocorrelations for
lags 1, 2, 3, and so on. The 'one-step' Markov dependence results
in significant autocorrelations for the first few lags, but after
a few lags autocorrelations as smaller. Smaller autocorrelations inside
the dotted blue lines are not considered significant.